# `y = atoi(x)` vs `x >> y` performance

Tags: c++, performance, stream, atoi

I need to parse a string containing a comma separated list of objects, like `a="1,2,3,4,5"`.
I also want the object type to be interchangeable, it is defined by `typedef type val_type`.

My approach is

```
vector<val_type> v();
istringstream iss(a); string x; val_type y;
while (getline(iss, x, ',') && istringstream(x) >> y) v.push_back(y);
```

Which works, but apparently runs much slower (about 5x) compared to using atoi() assuming the object type is an integer.

```
while (getline(iss, x, ',')) v.push_back(atoi(x.c_str()));
```

Is that huge difference in performance to be expected? Any clever way to get around this issue?

Comment: I don't know why you think `atoi(x)` is comparable to `x >> y` for any `y`, but it isn't.

Comment: "assuming the object type is an integer"

Comment: Performance issues are hard to discuss on this site. It depends on the implementation, build settings, and mostly the specifics of the project you're working on - for example what alternatives do you have, what constraints. These things are not a general topic; they're specific to your personal project. Your observation seems reasonable to me but how you decide to proceed is your choice.

Comment: The streaming classes have a bigger functionality and do more in the background compared to a simple atoi, so a performance loss is to be expected. If that is too slow for you you will have to implement your own conversion functions, or use the existing ones (btw, I'd use std::stoi instead of the c versions). The big question is how many different types are to be supported and how much importance plays performance at all

Comment: Okay, well actually I'd like to support any type that supports comparison. However, in practice I presume mostly `unsigned int` and `string` will be relevant. My main question was whether this performance difference is expected - and the answer I guess is 'yes'. BTW. why is stoi preferred over atoi?

Comment: Why aren't you doing `while (iss >> y) { v.push_back(y); char c; if (iss >> c && c != ',') throw std::runtime_error("garbage encountered instead of comma separator"); }`?  Go populating extra `string`s and `stringstream`s you deserve performance problems. ;-P

Comment: "BTW. why is stoi preferred over atoi?"  Why not read the relevant man pages... you'll see `atoi` has undefined behaviour on overflow, returns 0 for non-numeric input, while `stoi` checks and throws exceptions.

Comment: @TonyD

thanks for the answer. I can read but I also like to hear people's opinions.

i can't use `while (iss >> y) { v.push_back(y); char c; if (iss >> c && c != ',')` because e.g. for `string y` i would read across commas. yes, i could implement a new string type that doesn't, but that's not really what I want, I want to split on a specific delimiter no matter what the type.

Comment: @user3503380: oh, fair enough then :-).  It may be more practical to special case string handling then, as embedded spaces are also handled - potentially problematically - differently.